# Tracking Human Blob Associated with Face Detection

Tags: image-processing, opencv, machine-learning, image-recognition

I realize this is a non-trivial task, but what's the most practical method of detecting a face, and then tracking the body associated with that face in a video with moving background?

Detecting a face is fairly simple with OpenCV's trained [Haar cascade](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) for the face. Unfortunately, OpenCV's trained Haar cascades for the human body are so inaccurate as to be effectively unusuable, so my thought was to use the face detector to determine roughly where the "person" is, and then use something like [OpenTLD](http://www.ohloh.net/p/opentld) to dynamically "learn" what the person's body looks like and track that over frames. This should have the benefit of being able to handle a moving background, which most motion-tracking code in OpenCV currently doesn't seem to handle. The main downside is that OpenTLD is still quite new, and all the public implementations I've tested are very buggy and difficult to use.

Does this seem like a practical approach? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in human body detection/tracking rather than face detection, you should check people detection sample in the OpenCV. OpenCV contains a HoG descriptors and SVM classifier based people detector, which is actually one of the most successfull people detection algorithms available.